# Combinatorics in office.

Tags: combinatorics

John has 12 clients and he wants to use color coding to identify each client. If either a single color or a pair of two different colors can represent a client code, what is the minimun number of colors needed for coding? (the order of a pair of the colors do not matter)

Comment: The number $12$ is very small. One could try various numbers of colours $1,2,3,\dots$ until we find one that works.  For a much larger number of clients, formulas will be needed, since experimentation will be too time-consuming.

Comment: Aditya, I notice that all of your posted questions so far (with one exception) have simply stated a problem and asked for the answer.  This is really not the best way to use MSE.  You will get better, more useful answers (and fewer downvotes and votes to close) if you include a description of what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach: Consider $n$ colors and try to think about how many different combinations there are. There are $n$ single color choices and $\left(\begin{array}{c} n\\2\end{array}\right)$ color pair choices. So $n$ colors can represent a maximum of $c_n=n+\left(\begin{array}{c} n\\2\end{array}\right)$ clients for $n\geq2$.

This generates a sequence of numbers of clients: $1, 3, 6, 10, 15, \ldots$ for $n=1, 2, 3, 4, 5, \ldots$. Notice that $c_{n+1}=c_n+n+1$.

Since $10<12\leq15$, you will need 5 colors (i.e. 4 colors is not enough, but 5 is sufficient).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

$n$ colors induce $n+\binom{n}2$ distinct codes.

Answer (score 2):

1 -> 1 color,
3 ->2 color, 1,2,(12)
6 ->3 color, 1,2,3,(12)(23)(13)
10  ->4 color, 1,2,3,4,(12),(13)(14)(23)(24)(34) 
25 = 5+ c(5,2) ->5 color...

so 5 colors is enough.

Comment: I think you meant 15, not 25 = 5+ c(5,2).